# C# WPF MVVM My DataGrid Row is losing focus when I create a hash out of the DataGrid value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `datagrid` which works perfectly fine without the `hashfunction`.

Here the problem scenario:

I created a button, gave it a command (XAML) and created a `RelayCommand` in the `ViewModel` for that button.

Now the `RelayCommand` has a `CanExecute` Method, where I create a hash of the `DataTable` that is bound to my `DataGrid`.

I do that, so I can track changes that are made to the `DataTable`.

But every time if I insert or delete something in my `DataTable` (bound to `DataGrid`) the focus of the row in the `DataGrid` is lost.

I don't get why that occurs.

My `RelayCommand` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace AM.ViewModel
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields 
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        #endregion // Fields 
        #region Constructors 
        // Action<object> -> Verkapselung einer parameterlosen Methode 
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors 
        #region ICommand Members 
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
        #endregion // ICommand Members 
    }
}
```

The `Hashfunction` code:

```
private string CreateHash(DataTable dt)
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, dt);
    byte[] serializedData = memoryStream.ToArray();

    // Calculte the serialized data's hash value
    var SHA = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hash = SHA.ComputeHash(serializedData);

    // Convert the hash to a base 64 string
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

The `CanExecute` Method:

```
private bool SaveExecuteCommand(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        if (_InternalCheckActive)
        {
            hashCurrent = CreateHash(Adresses);

            if (!hashCurrent.Equals(hashSaved))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (_DBCheckActive)
        {
            hashCurrent = CreateHash(AdressesDBRelevant);

            if (!hashCurrent.Equals(hashSaved))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.Errorlogger.CheckDirectoyAndWriteToLog(ex);
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler - AdressManager", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

XAML of the button:

```
<Button Content="SaveTest" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Visibility="{Binding DataAvailabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleCommon}" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" IsTabStop="False" Focusable="False"/>
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML also?

Comment: I did. Was it the XAML of the button you wanted?

Comment: i suspect grid is loosing focus as it is being rebinded, just to be sure if thats happening, bing your grid.selectedItem to a property and see if that is  changed when you add something to dt, if you bind your grid to something that is observable you might find your issues disappear, or else you can persist the selected item and reselect it after dt is updated